# why is my maven plugin descriptor not being generated automatically?

Tags: maven, plugins, maven-descriptor

I have wrote my own plugin project and have run the command `mvn -install` through cygwin for my plugin project.
the jar file for it is being created in my repository, however when I execute my plugin, it says that my plugin descriptor is not present. I checked my jar file which was created and indeed it is not automatically created inside there.

I tried copying a sample `plugin.xml` and included it into my jar file and it worked. I would like to know if anyone knows why my plugin descriptor isn't created automatically?

Answer (score 19):

I always miss this but the packaging type is by default "jar" when you create the project in netbeans (and other ides), you have to remember to change it in your pom.xml to:

```
  <packaging>maven-plugin</packaging>
```

it is by default:

```
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
```

Answer (score 5):

I faced similar issue where in I had configured generation of plugin description file inside "target/dir" folder.I resolved the issue by removing any explicit configuration elements for the **maven-plugin-plugin**  declaration  from my pom.xml .

Then calling  "mvn package" generated the plugin.xml automatically during maven "packaging" phase.

Now if you call "mvn install" then you can observe that the plugin jar installed in your local maven repository would contain a "plugin.xml" under META-INF/maven folder.

Comment: Thanks! In my case, I removed only the `<outputDirectory>target/dir</outputDirectory>` line from my `pom.xml` and works!

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have configured the maven-plugin-plugin with the goal plugin:descriptor in your build section? 
If not, then manually executing the goal plugin:descriptor before install should also help.

Comment: hi dunni, I have tried plugin:descriptor and I still dont see the plugin.xml being created in my META-INF/maven folder.

Comment: Can you post the output of the mvn call? And try also executing Maven with the parameter -e or -X for debug messages (post the log at pastebin or similar services).

Comment: thanks man, i figured it out already
i left out <packaging>maven-plugin</packaging> in the pom file
hope this helps others

Answer (score 1):

I got the error when I ran `mvn compile`. When I ran `mvn test`, the error went away.