# unable to generate maven plugin.xml descriptor

Tags: maven, plugins, pom.xml, descriptor

EDIT : Solved was missing the tag `<packaging>maven-plugin</packaging>` in my project pom. I misunderstood the sentence in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7187379/why-is-my-maven-plugin-descriptor-not-being-generated-automatically?lq=1), didn't know the meaning of leaving out ...  :

> thanks man, i figured it out already i left out `<packaging>maven-plugin</packaging>` in the pom file hope this helps others

---

I'm trying to build a maven plugin however I can't get the plugin.xml file to be generated.

I've tried command line and pom configuration for maven-plugin-plugin, with/without descriptor goal and phase. I guess I'm doing it right there.

Probably it is the rest that is not done correctly. The only related topics that I found is [why is my maven plugin descriptor not being generated automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7187379/why-is-my-maven-plugin-descriptor-not-being-generated-automatically) and it doesn't help much.

Here is the maven log
http://pastebin.com/uA2KFTXN

I have two mojos with Java4 anotations (@goal and @phase). I have the following tags in my Pom

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <goalPrefix>signature</goalPrefix>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>descriptor</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>process-classes</phase>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Simple thing to check. What is the packaging type of your project? Also, `pom.xml` might be useful.